# Linked List sort only taking in the last line of a file in c

Tags: c, file, sorting, linked-list

This function is supposed to print the linked list of a file every time the for loop for j runs. The user inputs a number that they wish to sort by, for example, if they input '3' the program will sort by the 3rd element in the list. However, it is giving the incorrect output.

```
typedef struct Node
{
    char **data;    
    struct Node *next;
}Node;

Node *head = ( Node* )malloc( sizeof( Node ) );
head = NULL; //empty list

void categoryStore( FILE* fpi, int numCols, int numRows, Node *head )
{

    void addStart(Node**, char**, int );
    void insertionSort( Node**, char**, int, int );
    void printLinkedList( Node*, int );

    int i = 0, j = 0, ret = 0, userinput;
    char *firstLine, *dump, **catstore;

    dump = ( char* )malloc( 50*sizeof( char ) );
    firstLine = ( char* )malloc( 50*sizeof( char ) );
    catstore = ( char** )malloc( 50*numCols*sizeof( char* ) );

    do
    {
        scanf( "%d", &userinput ); /* let the user select the catagory via a number */

        if( userinput >= 0 && userinput < numCols)
        {

            fscanf( fpi,"%s%*[^\n]\n", firstLine );

            for( j = 0; j < numRows; j++ )
            {

                for(i = 0; i <= numCols - 1; i++)
                {
                    catstore[i] = ( char* )malloc( 50*sizeof( char ) );

                    if( i < numCols - 1 )
                    {
                        fscanf( fpi, "%[^,],", catstore[i] );
                    }

                    else
                    {
                        fscanf( fpi, "%[^\n]\n", catstore[i] );
                    }


                }

                if( j == 0 )
                {
                    addStart( &head, catstore, numCols );
                    printLinkedList( head, numCols );
                }

                else
                {
                    insertionSort( &head, catstore, userinput, numCols );
                    printLinkedList( head, numCols );
                }

            }

        }

        else if( userinput == numCols )
        {
            printf( "goodbye\n" );
        }

        else
        {
            printf( "Invalid input, please try again\n" );
            ret = -1;
        }

    }while( ret != 0 );

}  


  /* function to add a node to the start of the linkedlist */
void addStart( Node** head, char **line, int numCols )
{
    int i;

    Node *temp = ( Node* )malloc( sizeof( Node ) ); //create and temporarily store the address of temp
    temp->data = ( char** )malloc( 50*numCols*sizeof( char* ) );
    temp->data = line;

    for( i = 0; i < numCols; i++ )
    {
        strcpy( temp->data[i], line[i] );
    }


    temp->next = *head; //dereferences temp and points the element "next" to what head is pointing to


    *head = temp; //now head points to temp
}


/* function to insert addition lines and sort them */

void insertionSort(Node **head, char **line, int select, int numCols)
{
    int i;
    Node *temp = ( Node* )malloc( sizeof( Node ) );
    temp->data = ( char** )malloc( 50*numCols*sizeof( char* ) );
    temp->data = line;

    for( i = 0; i < numCols; i++ )
    {
        strcpy( temp->data[i], line[i] );
    }

    Node *temp1, *temp2;
    temp1 = *head;
    temp2 = *head;
    temp1 = temp1->next;


    if( strcmp( temp2->data[select], temp->data[select] ) >= 0 )
    {
        temp->next = temp2;
        *head = temp;
    }
    else
    {

        if(temp1->next != NULL)
        {

            while( strcmp( temp1->data[select], temp->data[select] ) < 0 && temp1->next != NULL )
            {
                temp1 = temp1->next;
                temp2 = temp2->next;
            }

            if ( temp1->next == NULL && strcmp( temp1->data[select], temp->data[select] ) < 0 )
            {
                temp->next = NULL;
                temp1->next = temp;
            }

            else
            {
                temp2->next = temp;
                temp->next = temp1;
            }
        }

        else
        {
            if( strcmp( temp1->data[select], temp->data[select] ) < 0 )
            {
                temp->next = NULL;
                temp1->next = temp;
            }

            else
            {   
                temp2->next = temp;
                temp->next = temp1;
            }
        }   
    }
}


/* print the linked list */  
void printLinkedList( Node* head, int numCols )
{
    while( head != NULL )
    {
        int i=0;
        for (i = 0; i < numCols; i++)
        {
            printf( "%s", head->data[i] );
        }
        printf( "\n" );
        head = head->next;
    }   
}
```

The input file contains:

name (string), age (integer), address (string), food (string), colour (string)
mark, 21, at home, cheese, yellow
jordan, 19, his place, cupcake, dark blue
john, 40, mt everest, salad, red
geralt, 100, kaer morhan, wolf, white
sam, 50, the shire, potatoes and strawberries, green

If the input was 3

The output should be:

mark 21 at home cheese yellow

mark 21 at home cheese yellow
jordan 19 his place cupcake dark blue

mark 21 at home cheese yellow
jordan 19 his place cupcake dark blue
john 40 mt everest salad red

mark 21 at home cheese yellow
jordan 19 his place cupcake dark blue
geralt 100 kaer morhan wolf white
john 40 mt everest salad red

mark 21 at home cheese yellow
jordan 19 his place cupcake dark blue
geralt 100 kaer morhan wolf white
john 40 mt everest salad red
sam 50 the shire potatoes and strawberries green

The output currently is:

mark 21 at home cheese yellow
jordan 19 his place cupcake dark blue
jordan 19 his place cupcake dark blue
john 40 mt everest salad red
john 40 mt everest salad red
john 40 mt everest salad red
geralt 100 kaer morhan wolf white
geralt 100 kaer morhan wolf white
geralt 100 kaer morhan wolf white
geralt 100 kaer morhan wolf white
sam 50 the shire potatoes and strawberries green
sam 50 the shire potatoes and strawberries green
sam 50 the shire potatoes and strawberries green
sam 50 the shire potatoes and strawberries green
sam 50 the shire potatoes and strawberries green

It appears as though the last line read is being taken in every time the function is called, and is replacing every line that is currently in the linked list. Could anyone tell me why this is happening. Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks.

Comment: Those three prototypes should be out of the `categoryStore` function, shouldn't they? (Just to clarify, obviously this won't resolve your problem).

Comment: At the beginning of `addStart` and `insertionSort`, the variable `temp->data` is being assigned twice, first with the result of malloc, and then with the argument `line`. When you make the second assignment, you're losing the reference for your allocated memory, so you can't free it later. This is surely causing memory leak.

Comment: Hi @Milack, thanks for your comment. When I tried to remove `temp->data` (the second occurence), a segmentation fault occurs at the strcpy line.

Comment: @wildplasser sorry, i forgot to add in my struct `Node` . it's at the top of the code now.

Comment: Oh, I see some supsicious points here. First, you're initializing `head` twice. I'm surprised your compiler lets you do that out of a function. I think you meant `Node *head = NULL`, remove the malloc. Also, at `addStart`, `temp->next` is a pointer, but you're assigning `*head` to it, which is a full struct. Again, I'm surprised your compiler lets you do that without a warning, or even an error. I think you meant `temp->next = head`. Next line, you're doing just the opposite, filling a struct with a pointer. I think you meant `head = temp`. Similar considerations apply to `insertionSort`.

Comment: Also, I see a lot of `malloc` calls, but I don't see any `free` call. If you're serious about C programming, you've got to fix that.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the array of pointers for catstore is only allocated one time, so each new line overwrites all the field pointers from any previous lines. You need to move the line that allocates an array of pointers, and it only needs to allocate numCols pointers.

```
            for( j = 0; j < numRows; j++ )
            {
                /* moved this line, deleted the "50 *"  */
                catstore = ( char** )malloc( numCols*sizeof( char* ) );
                for(i = 0; i <= numCols - 1; i++)
                {
```

insertionSort() needs to be fixed / cleaned up. If you fix insertionSort() so that it handles an empty list, you can get rid of addStart().

```
    /* delete this line */
    temp->data = ( char** )malloc( 50*numCols*sizeof( char* ) );

    /* this line is ok */ 
    temp->data = line;
```